# Brewing GRASS with PostgreSQL support?

Tags: postgis, grass-gis, installation, osx, homebrew

On my Mac, running OS X 10.10.5 and I installed Grass with homebrew:

```
brew tap osgeo/osgeo4mac
brew install grass-70
```

Unfortunately, I cannot choose the `pg` driver in the `db.login` menu.

[image]

Can anyone tell me how to install it or how to brew Grass with the `pg` driver activated?

Comment: Questions about compiling software, even GIS software, are general software development problems, more suited to Stack Overflow

Comment: The question is regarding a specific aspect relating to gis and not a general installation question. Asking this question on a non-gis group would likely not have attracted attention.

Comment: As Rainer said, I believe I would not have received an answer on any other SE site. The availability and description of the tags `installation` and `installer` suggests that setup of GIS software seems to be part of GIS.stackexchange.com. Somehow I can't seem to add the latter tag.

Comment: @Mapperz I am still puzzeled that this question was closed. GIS.SE is full with these kind of questions...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you look at the grass-70 recipe info from homebrew, you'll see:

```
Rainers-MacBook-Pro:~ rainerkrug$ brew info grass-70
osgeo/osgeo4mac/grass-70: stable 7.0.1
Geographic Resources Analysis Support System
http://grass.osgeo.org/
/usr/local/Cellar/grass-70/7.0.1 (3708 files, 83M) *
  Built from source with: --with-mysql --with-postgresql --with-liblas
From: https://github.com/osgeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac/blob/master/Formula/grass-70.rb
==> Dependencies
Build: pkg-config ✔
Required: gettext ✔, readline ✔, gdal ✔, libtiff ✔, unixodbc ✔, fftw ✔, wxpython ✔, cairo ✔, ghostscript ✔
Optional: openblas ✘, liblas ✔, netcdf ✔, ffmpeg ✔
==> Options
--with-ffmpeg
    Build with ffmpeg support
--with-liblas
    Build with liblas support
--with-mysql
    Build with mysql support
--with-netcdf
    Build with netcdf support
--with-openblas
    Build with openblas support
--with-postgresql
    Build with postgresql support
--without-gui
    Build without WxPython interface. Command line tools still available.
Rainers-MacBook-Pro:~ rainerkrug$
```

The important line is:

```
--with-postgresql
    Build with postgresql support
```

In other words - the default install of grass-70 via homebrew **does not** include postgresql support.

So to install grass with postgresql, you have to use:

```
brew install grass-70 --with-postgresql
```

This will also install all the necessary dependencies.